# Среда разработки

Tags: c#, c, java, c++

Где можно писать программы на C, C#, C++, java?
Можно разные среды, только чтобы были бесплатные и шли на windows 8.1.

Comment: > C№

Visual Studio Express

> C, C++

Visual Studio Express, Netbeans, Codeblocks

> java

Visual Studio Express, Netbeans, Aptana

Список, понятное дело, и близко не полный.

Comment: Ну, они все бесплатные?


Мне для учебы нужно.  
Просто будем изучать, я не знаю, что качать и где(

Comment: Для java исключительно intelliJ IDEA (есть бесплатная версия).

Comment: Да это я уже скачала.  
А вот для всего, что связано с С, не знаю, что делать(

Comment: Для C ничего особенного не надо для изучения, достаточно редактора с подсветкой кода (Vim, Emacs, SublimeText) и компилятора

Comment: Не дотягивает до ответа, но очень рекомендую посмотреть в сторону Intel C++, для студентов они дают полную лицензию на год, при этом в комплекте идет такой набор утилит, аналайзеров и профайлеров, что мама не горюй. Интегрируется с Visual Studio, и после интеграции работать с VS без нее Вы уже никогда не сможете. И даже не пожалеете 700 баксов на лицензию, если будете этим зарабатывать.

Answer (score 6):

Для C#:

1. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) - во многом лучший выбор для C#, поскольку стабильна и вполне удобна. Из недостатоков - не кроссплатфроменна и  не поддерживает дополнения (если это важно, то тут надо использовать не бесплатные версии этого продукта).
2. [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/studio) - с одной стороны, лишена вышеописанных недостатков Visual Studio Express (то есть и кроссплатформенна, и дополнения ставить можно), а с другой стороны, весьма грешит нестабильностью работы и довольно дурацкими багами (например, у меня недавно на ней перестала работать комбинация Ctrl+C, тогда как на официальном сайте говорится, что ошибка давно исправлена).

Java:

1. [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - многими небезосновательно считается лучшей IDE в природе. Есть и в бесплатной редакции Community Edition.
2. Классика жанра [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr1) - очень популярная IDE, с виду может показаться несколько неказистой, но расширяется миллионом дополнений.
3. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). Про эту среду, к сожалению, ничего сказать не могу.

С++:

1. Все те же Visual Studio Express, Eclipse и NetBeans.
2. Недавно появившаяся [CLion](http://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). Пока еще не финальный релиз, но вроде очень даже ничего.
3. [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) не относится к "взрослым" Ide, но зато легковесна и вполне удобна для новичка.
4. Еще один весьма небезызвестный и многими любимый продукт - [QTCreator](http://qt-project.org/downloads).
5. Не бесплатная, но достойная упоминания вещь [Embarcadero RAD Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/rad-studio), включает в себя известный многим бывший С++ Builder.

Все вышеперечисленные IDE, кроме последней, бесплатны (впрочем для учебы, наверное, можно скачать и кряк). Кроме того, у некоторых платных продуктов есть свои бесплатные лицензии для студентов.

Comment: @DreamChild, я же говорил что за орфографию можно не переживать ;-) Всеравно все Виталина исправит.По Xamarin я бы еще добавил что она еще жутко неудобная после VS.

Comment: @z668, Что касается Xamarin Studio - она не то что неудобна, но требует привычки - многие средства в ней тоже есть, только их нужно найти. Наиболее критично (ну лично для меня) отсутствие решарпера (хотя это не вина разработчиков), какой-то невнятный Nuget и общее количество багов (многие из них, вроде бы даже уже исправленные, регулярно всплывают)

Comment: "Visual Studio Express - во многом лучший выбор для C#, поскольку стабильна и вполне удобна. Из недостатоков - не кроссплатфроменна и не поддерживает дополнения" 
Что имеется ввиду под дополнениями? Сторонние библиотеки/компоненты нельзя использовать?

Answer (score 3):

Я на C# пишу в SharpDevelop и счастлив

Comment: Она бесплатна, но ограничена. До VS однозначно не дотягивает, даже до Express.

Comment: Ограничена, но мне хватает с головой. Тем более она поддерживает самописные плагины, так что тут полет фонтазии ограничен только объемом знаний

Answer (score 3):

Очень сомневаюсь, что начинающему (причем такому, который вряд ли станет "продолжающим") вообще нужна IDE. Возьми Sublime Text для всего и не мучайся. А программы запускай в командной строке. Заодно избавишься от мерзейшей привычки всех студентов пихать в конец программы какую-нибудь ересь типа getch(), чтобы, видите ли, окошко у нее, болезной, не закрывалось. Компилятор для C - TCC, для остального - майкрософт (не лучшие, но тут главное "как у всех").

Но если предполагается изучать главным образом Java (а все остальное - так, для разгона), то настоятельно рекомендую BlueJ. Мне, когда я с какого-то перепугу заинтересовался Джавой несколько лет назад, она очень понравилась. Это специальная среда для начинающих, чтобы сразу понимали, что программа - это не код, это архитектура. Кто посоветует мне что-нибудь похожее на BlueJ, но для любого (буквально, т.е. хоть для Кобола) другого языка - буду признателен.